# Updating avatar on Ruby on Rails with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've looked around and I cannot figure out why this is working. I allow users to sign up, without needing them to upload avatars at first. However, if they wish, they can upload avatars after signing up. I allow them to edit their avatar in a "profiles" controller, not in the user controller. However, the avatar won't update. I'm using devise for the users. Code below

```
<%= form_for edit_user_path(current_user.id), :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= form.submit "upload" %>
<% end %>
```

And in the Users controller, I have this:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update_attribute(:avatar, params[:user][:avatar])
end
```

And in the user model, I have this

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :show => "150x150#" }, :default_url => 'missing_:style.png'
```

The avatar does not update or save. I'm not sure why.

Update with new form code:

```
<%= form_for current_user, :url => {:action => 'update'}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= form.submit "upload" %>
<% end %>
```

In the profiles controller, I have this:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update_attribute(:avatar, params[:user][:avatar])
end
```

I get this error: undefined method `name' for #

Parameters being passed on the request are below

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"cxANtlyj+W+ykSnivfQTfTznkpt7yXe75E8jWI1IC+o=",
 "user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001032ac7c8         @original_filename="pictester.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\";     filename=\"pictester.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/x9/gvnnn6s9585gkxw40c51d3540000gn/T/RackMultipart20130622-    10366-a8ome3>>},
 "commit"=>"upload",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: How is your avatar attribute defined in the user model? Do you have something like `has_attached_file :avatar`?

Comment: yes, i will update my code

Comment: Just out of curiosity: You wrote, you have a special profiles controller where users can upload an avatar. In your post you say: "And in the Users controller, I have this:". Typo? Or is the code placed incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating attributes is done inside `def update`, not `def edit`. This is for rendering the form.

In `profiles_controller.rb`

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attribute(:avatar, params[:user][:avatar])
end
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a little confused, still. What would I do with the form? I'm rendering the form in the Index action of the profiles controller so that users can update their avatar from their profile. If I set the form's action to update, Rails complains after uploading a photo with this error: undefined method `name' for #<User:0x00000106ca19d8>. I will update my code

Comment: Usually, `index` shows a list of things, e.g. users. It renders `index.html.erb`. `show` renders one item. `edit` shows a form to edit one item and `update` is called when you click Update or Save in the `edit` view.

Comment: I know, but I'm not using Index to show all the users as my app doesn't require it. It's against convention, I know. I'm just showing one user as it's all I have a need for. And I just didn't want to have to make the user go to a separate page to upload their avatar. Why not from their own profile? I could render edit as a partial, but I'm not sure if that would make a difference?

Comment: Even if you use a singleton controller, you should use `show` instead of index. In any case, clicking Update should call `ProfilesController#update`, right?

Comment: After you changed your code in the post: Do you have only the avatar field or more like name? And is this defined as an attribute to the users class, too?

Comment: Right now I'm just testing updating the avatar. Avatar is the only thing in the form, so I'm not sure why name is showing up

Comment: Also, now I'm getting an error: No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"profiles"}, despite the fact it shows up on rake routes...